# How to create a label for Node in neo4j REST batch API(use Unique Indexing)?

Tags: neo4j

when i use   **POST /db/data/batch**
`[
   {
      "body" : {
         "mark" : 0,
         "userId" : 1
      },
      "id" : 1,
      "method" : "POST",
      "to" : "/node"
   },
   {
      "body" : "SinaUserBean",
      "method" : "POST",
      "to" : "{1}/labels"
   }
]`
it well done!
but i use   **POST /db/data/batch**
`[
   {
      "body" : {
         "key" : "userId",
         "properties" : {
            "mark" : 0,
            "userId" : 1
         },
         "value" : 1
      },
      "id" : 1,
      "method" : "POST",
      "to" : "/index/node/SinaUserBean?uniqueness=get_or_create"
   },
   {
      "body" : "SinaUserBean",
      "method" : "POST",
      "to" : "{1}/labels"
   }
]`
it will be **500** anf return 
`{
   "exception" : "BatchOperationFailedException",
   "fullname" : "org.neo4j.server.rest.domain.BatchOperationFailedException",
   "message" : "",
   "stacktrace" : [
      "org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.NonStreamingBatchOperations.invoke(NonStreamingBatchOperations.java:63)",
      "org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.BatchOperations.performRequest(BatchOperations.java:201)",
      "org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.BatchOperations.parseAndPerform(BatchOperations.java:171)",
      "org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.NonStreamingBatchOperations.performBatchJobs(NonStreamingBatchOperations.java:48)",
      "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.BatchOperationService.batchProcess(BatchOperationService.java:126)",
      "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.BatchOperationService.performBatchOperations(BatchOperationService.java:76)",
      "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)",
      "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)",
      "org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)",
      "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)"
   ]
}`
 I also want to ask that what the **{id}** will be replaced ,like this**/db/data/node/*realId***,or other

Comment: In fact,I just want to **Incremental Batch Import**，I find the rest API is good!But i also have some trouble in using the rest API.

Comment: In fact,I just want to **Incremental Batch Import**，I find the rest API is good!But i also have some trouble in using the rest API. such as: Repeating relationship and repeating nodes will be insert，[Unique Indexing](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-unique-indexes.html)! I want to do that if the node or relationship exist ,it can be covered or directly return node，if not exist create!Maybe I used a stupid way!sigh~